# How to install Sublime packages in Ubuntu

Tags: package, sublimetext3

I am able to install the package control in Ubuntu 14 by using Terminal (Command Line) since it needs admin privileges to copy the file into the package directory.
But I am not able to install any package since it needs admin privileges again. 
Please suggest some way to install a new package for sublime in Linux (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

In sublime, you can press *' Ctrl + shift + p'*, *install package* and then install whatever package you want.

I don't think you need any sudo rights to do this.

Hope this helps.